# Modifying search or making custom search in Visual Studio Code Extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am currently trying to make an extension in visual studio that uses the results from the normal search and shows the results in it's own view that does not display the found results per file, but per user-defined modules.

For example the usual search gives:
4 results found in 3 files

- src/extension.ts (2 results)
- folder2/file1.ts (1 result)
- folder2/file2.ts (1 result)

Then my extension could show:
4 results found in 2 modules

- src/ (2 results)
- folder2/ (2 results)

For this I looked up the [Contribution points](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/contribution-points#contributes.menus) and in "contributes.menus" there is the Explorer context menu that contains the group "4_search" - Commands related to searching in the search view.

How can I use this contribution point for my extension? Is it even feasible to use the search results and show the data in a new view like the example above?

Edit:
I realised that I did not understand the contribution points at all when asking and it is not what I need. Do you know how I can execute a command whenever the user searches for something in the search view and get the search results as parameters for the command?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: you connect a command to the specified menu.

Comment: Thanks for your help @rioV8
I connected a command to the specified menu as I asked in the question but I realised that I did not understand the contribution points at all when asking and it is not what I need. 
Do you know how I can execute a command whenever the user searches for something in the search view and get the search results as parameters for the command?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.